# Are there any other Java Repository Managers apart from Nexus, Artifactory and Archiva?

Tags: ivy, nexus, artifactory, archiva, binary-repository

I'm trying to identify software that will allow me to easily proxy & cache Maven and Ivy repositories.  The main aims are:

- prevent access to unexpected 3rd-party repositories by build scripts
- audit which versions of libs are used
- speed up builds by reducing external internet traffic across our team
- reduce external bandwidth usage

The candidates I have found are:

- [Archiva](https://archiva.apache.org/index.cgi)
- [Artifactory](http://www.jfrog.com/open-source/#os-arti)
- [Nexus](http://www.sonatype.org/nexus/)

Are there any I have missed?

Comment: No. As far as i know there are no other repository managers. Just take Nexus (OSS), Artifactory(OSS) or Archiva. From my point of view Nexus(OSS) is very simple to use and very simple to install and very fast.

Comment: A good source of information is the [Maven Repository Manager Feature Matrix](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVENUSER/Maven+Repository+Manager+Feature+Matrix)

Comment: @khmarbaise Artifactory is about five times faster than Nexus (all the rest, e.g. easy to install and use are subjectives, but speed is measurable)

Comment: @JBaruch five times faster response?  or downloading from it?  or will I get 5x faster builds?!

Comment: @drorb thanks - seen that.  It only has the 3 options I mentioned in the question.

Comment: Well, the build time consists of tons of things, e.g. compile time, tests time, etc. All those have nothing to do with the binary repository. Download time consists of 2 main things - the repository work (finding the needed artifact, reading it, sending to socket) and download time. The later is out of our control. The former is 5 times faster.

Comment: @JBaruch five times faster response? I'm interested to know how do you get those figures and how Archiva is in your benchmark.

Comment: We are planning to opensource the tests (gatling scripts), so you'll be able to run them against Archiva.

Answer (score 1):

There is also Package Drone (http://packagedrone.org/) now. Although relatively new it has some interesting features, especially if you are interested at all in doing something with OSGi.

Answer (score 0):

There's Project Wolf from JBoss.  Apparently, it's packaged with EAP 6.

There seems to be activity in their JIRA Activity Stream in 2015.

Sources:

[JIRA link](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WOLF/?selectedTab=com.atlassian.jira.jira-projects-plugin:summary-panel)

[Slide presentation](http://www.slideshare.net/maxandersen/jboss-enterprise-maven-repository?related=1)

[Technology Preview](https://access.redhat.com/maven-repository)